# Exercise III.2.1(b) Hartshorne: Isn't the restriction of a constant sheaf on a connected space to a connected subspace again constant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

Consider Exercise III.2.1(b) in Hartshorne: Let $X=\mathbb{A}_k^n$ for $n\geq 2$ and an infinite field $k$, and let $Y\subseteq X$ be the union of $n+1$ hyperplanes in general position. Let $U=X\setminus Y$, and denote by $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ the constant sheaf on $X$, and also $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_U:=j_{!}(j^{-1}\underline{\mathbb{Z}})$ as well as $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_Y:=i_{*}(i^{-1}\underline{\mathbb{Z}})$, where $j:U\to X$ and $i:Y\to X$ are the inclusion maps. Then show that $H^n(X,\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_U)\neq 0$.

Now I'm confused: consider the sheaf $i^{-1}\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ on $Y$. By definition, this is the sheaf associated to the presheaf $i^{-1,pre}\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ defined by
$$
i^{-1,pre}\underline{\mathbb{Z}}(W)=\lim_{\substack{V\subseteq_{\text{open}} X \\ W\subseteq V}}\underline{\mathbb{Z}}(V).
$$
But now as $X$ is irreducible, we have $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}(V)=\mathbb{Z}$ for all non-empty $V$, and the restriction maps are just the identity, so $i^{-1,pre}\underline{\mathbb{Z}}(W)=\mathbb{Z}$ for all non-empty $W$. But now as $Y$ is connected for $n\geq 2$, this is in fact already a sheaf, namely the constant sheaf associated to $\mathbb{Z}$ on $Y$. But then this is flasque, so the higher cohomology groups vanish, which gives me $H^n(X,\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_U)=0$. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue is that the answer to your question in the title is negative, since it's *irreducibility* that you're really interested in to argue that this sheaf is flasque. Explicitly, if you take the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes in the affine plane $Y=V(xy) \subseteq \mathbf{A}^2_k$ and the constant sheaf $\underline{\mathbf{Z}} \in \text{Sh}_{\text{Ab}}(Y)$ (which is the restriction of the constant sheaf $\underline{\mathbf{Z}}$ on $\mathbf{A}^2_k$ to $X$) then the global sections are given by $\Gamma(Y,\underline{\mathbf{Z}}) = \mathbf{Z}$ since $Y$ is connected, but $Y$ has the disconnected open subset $U = D(x) \cup D(y) \subseteq Y$. You can see $U$ is disconnected by the equality $$
   D(x) \cap D(y) = D(xy) = \emptyset
$$ or by just checking that $U$'s global sections are given by the equaliser $$
   \text{eq}(k[x,x^{-1}] \times k[y,y^{-1}] \rightrightarrows (0)) = k[x,x^{-1}] \times k[y,y^{-1}]
$$ which has precisely two non-trivial idempotents - this implies $\Gamma(U,\underline{\mathbf{Z}}) = \mathbf{Z} \oplus \mathbf{Z}$ and thus the restriction map $$
   \Gamma(Y,\underline{\mathbf{Z}}) \to \Gamma(U,\underline{\mathbf{Z}})
$$ can't be surjective.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Ah yes of course, thanks :)